calling a sql function in SSIS OLEDB destination
I want to implement encryption in SSIS to replace linked server
Here is old code using TSQL
truncate table dest_table;
insert into dest_table
SELECT id, EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SymKey'),cast(sensitive as varchar)) as sensitive_encr, other_fields
FROM [linked_server]...[MyTable]

However I didn't find a way to call a function in SSIS destination. I can construct insert statement in OLE DB Command Transformation but it means slow row by row processing. The only solution I found is to vertically partition destination table to two tables - wide one without sensitive field and narrow one with id and sensitive field. Next I will use Execute SQL task to reload it with encryption like
truncate table dest_encr
insert into dest_encr 
select id, EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SymKey'),cast(sensitive as varchar)) as sensitive_encr from narrow_table
truncate table narrow_table

So my question is - is it ever possible to call sql scalar function in SSIS oledb destination?
